# Likely to fail components in amplifier board

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, troubleshooting, failure

I'm troubleshooting a car audio amplifier that has no life except for power led.

I'd like to avoid having to pull it in a million pieces to find the broken component(s), so:
What are the most likely to fail components in an audio amplifier?

Here's a [large image of the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcHgy.jpg):

[image: Large image of the board]

Someone told me to check the rectifiers on the left which check okay. I also tested the large transistors on the right and they check fine.

Edit: The supply voltage is 12volts DC. It's an AB class amp with positive and negative rails and 4 output channels.

**Edit2:** The question is not "How to repair X" it clearly states "What components are likely to fail first?"

Comment: Maybe give some more detail on how you checked the transistors and the rectifiers and what exactly you measured. What about supply voltages?

Comment: Did you take this 'photo' with a flatbed scanner?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No. I actually composited ~20 photos from a low quality camera to get something readable.

Comment: Interesting image. It's like Google Earth for Electronics...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a stereo amplifier, and neither channel is working, the most likely culprit is the power supply.  Electrolytic capacitors have the highest failure rates so I would start with them. Look for any sign of burning or charring.  Check out any voltage regulators. If you can power up the amplifier it would be easier to trace the supply voltage through the board.

Answer (score 1):

Test that nasty-looking swollen cap on the left with its plastic sleeve half-gone.

Better yet, replace it

Comment: It's the image composition. All caps appear(visibly) to be in top notch shape.